# Twitter-bootstrap modal doesn't work in angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a bootstrap modal in angular 7, but the modal is not working.

In my `angular.json` file in scripts I am including `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` in this order.

My component.html:

```
<button type="button" class="catalogue-button btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
         data-target="catalogueModal">Katalog</button>
         <!-- The Modal -->
         <div class="modal" id="catalogueModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">

                  <!-- Modal Header -->
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Modal body -->
                  <div class="modal-body">
                     Modal body..
                  </div>

                  <!-- Modal footer -->
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>

               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

When I click on the button nothing happens. The browser console is empty too.

I am using this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: did you added reference to the bootstrap css? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: yes, I added the reference in the `angular.json` file

Comment: is there a reason your using twitter-bootstrap? why not use an adapted [ng framework](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) with bootstrap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/). Its an ability to use bootstrap „the angular way“ without the need of jquery.

It is well documented and you will find many small examples. [Here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) is the documentation for using a modal.

Answer (score 2):

To open a modal do the following modifications in your code:

insert new button into your component.html file:

```
<button (click)="showModal()">Show</button>
```

In your typescript file for the same component add this method:

```
  showModal() {
    $("#catalogueModal").modal('show');
  }
```

at the top of the file before `@Component` add this line:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Comment: mm we should try to avoid manipulating the dom directly through jquery in Angular..